# Convert.DateTime

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

What Convert.DateTime will convert the date 7/25/2010 12:00:00 it's current format is(MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss)?

When I convert this string format to date time I am getting the error "**string was not recognized as valid DateTime**"

Comment: Could you please clarify which is the input and which is the output?  What is the data type of each?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

None. Dates are not stored internally as a certain format.

If you want to parse a string into a date, use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) (the former will throw an exception if the conversion fails, the second uses an `out` parameter):

```
DateTime myDate = DateTime.ParseExact("7/25/2010 12:00:00", 
                                      "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss",
                                      CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If you want to **display** a certain format, use `ToString` with the format string.

So, if you have a date object that represents midday of the 25th of July 2010 (doesn't matter how it is represented internally) and you want to format it with the format string "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss" you do the following:

```
string formattedDate = myDate.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss");
```

Answer (score 0):

`DateTime.TryParse()` or `DateTime.Parse()` will do the trick.

Edit: This is assuming that you are going *from* a string *to* a DateTime object.

Edit2: I just tested this with your input string, and I receive no error with `DateTime.Parse`

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use Convert.DateTime, I'll assume you're working with a string you want to convert to a date. So you might try this:

```
DateTime date = Convert.DateTime("7/25/2010 12:00:00 am");
string formattedDateString = date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss")
```

I'm making no assumptions as to why you'd want to do this, except that, well, you have your reasons.

Comment: i need to store this string formatted date into the database in the form of DateTime.but when i am trying to store it it gives me the "string was not recognized as valid DateTime" error

Comment: Are you getting this error when you try to convert it to DateTime or when you try to store the converted DateTime into the database? If it's the second, what database are you using?